# Specifyig executable name in sudoers in order pass password

Tags: security, automation

Why has put an executable name in `/etc/sudoers`, but run it still get asked password?

This is what I have inserted in the file `/etc/sudoers` by the command `$ sudo visudo /etc/sudoers` (user name illustrative)

```
foobar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/lsblk
```

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/lsblk
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 137168 Jun 27 21:32 /usr/bin/lsblk
```

But still ask password, how to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo` system doesn't give you the privilege all the time - you must invoke it. Use:

```
# as user "foobar"
# forget credentials 
sudo -k
#
sudo /usr/bin/lsblk
# and you won't be asked for a psssword
# now, you will be asked
sudo id
```

Read `man sudo`